# How to change Labels (come from array) color when i click same text in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

strong text i am using zim framework that come from Javascript, i got list (array) of words same words will appear in label (words in label come also from array) 
///

```
label2 = new Label({
        currentSelected:true,
        font:"thuluth",
        color:"white",
        rollColor:"red",
  }).pos(570,100)
  .change(function (e) {// e is the event object
    list.selectedIndex = e.target.selectedIndex
    labelsindex=e.target.label2;

    })
      mainTransManager.add(label2);
      label2.transform({handleSize:8}); 
      stage.update();            
}//end for
```

//list code

```
list = new List({
    list:labelsList,
    width:200,
    height:400,
    align:"center", 
    indent:0, 
    labelIndent:10, 
    borderColor:light,
    viewNum:8,
    corner:10,
    titleBar:"OPTIONS",
    titleBarBackgroundColor:light,
    scrollBarActive:true,
    close:true,
    currentSelected:true,
    boundary:new Boundary(5,5,stageW-215,stageH-400-70)
}).pos(800,100)
  .on("click", function(e) {
   label2.selectedIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
    if(label2.text=e.target.text){
       label2.color="green";
    }
    stage.update();
})
mainTransManager.persist("ex1");  
stage.update();
```

});